# wpf excel like grid editing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In a project I have a very tricky requirement I don't know how to solve:

I have several datagrids in a single wpf window (I use MVVM) all binded to some collection in the linked ViewModel. 
The customer wants to edit each of these grids, either within the grid or in a common textbox (like in excel).

I'm banging the head on how to do the latter. What I would do is bind the textbox with a property in the viewmodel, but when the value is changed there, I need to change the value in the original property binded with the datagrid cell accordingly. In other words, I need to know what collection and which property of that collection I need to change with the data in the textbox accordingly .

I tried several ways but with no luck.

Reflection? DependencyProperty? What else?

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: This is still a little vague.  Are you saying you want to have an external textbox bound to a particular value on the grid so that when the user clicks a cell in that grid, the value of the textbox is bound to it?

Comment: Yes, anytime a user clicks a cell that value is bound to the textbox, and when he changes it in the textbox the changes are reflected to the cell (and of course to the object bound to it in the viewmodel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the built-in WPF `DataGrid`, you'll need to setup your grid similarly:

```
    <DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged">
        ...
    </DataGrid>
```

Also give your `TextBox` a name:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
```

In the code-behind, you'll need to manually wire up this event, since apparently the `DataGrid` doesn't allow you to bind to the selected item/cell/value when using `SelectionUnit="Cell"`:

```
private void DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedCells.Count == 0)
        this.textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, (string) null);
    else
    {
        var selectedCell = e.AddedCells.First();

        // Assumes your header is the same name as the field it's bound to
        var binding = new Binding(selectedCell.Column.Header.ToString())
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Source = selectedCell.Item,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
        this.textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

I tried getting this done without code-behind but after looking around it didn't seem like this was possible.

Comment: thanks, I came to the same solution. Anyway I don't think this is a 'violation' of MVVM pattern since this is pure View logic. If I would change view technology, I can get rid of this code without affecting viewmodel logic in any way and (most important) I don't have any refence to any view specific class (such as SelecetedCellChangedEventArgs) in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tencntraze answer I used this code to get te property bound to the cell

```
var property = (selectedCell.Column.ClipboardContentBinding as Binding).Path.Path;
```